# Are our biological parents our spiritual brothers and sisters?

Tags: creation, soul, spirituality

I have been wondering lately is that Allah created all as souls at same time so that's makes us all brothers and sister but when we are born those who bore us makes them our parent. So does that mean that they are biologically our parents, but in spirituality there our brothers sister? Or there are still our parents even if we created at same time?

Answer (score 1):

**Allah created all the souls of the descendants of Adam and Hawa who were predestined to come to this earth**. Everything about the universes and our soul before and after creations are documented and recorded in the tablet (book) board in heaven(Lau Ho Mahfuz).

All his descendant's **bodies** are created by sperm of man and ovum of women.

Allah **breathed into the body of man part of His spirit called (Ruh) Soul** . When the soul enters the body it becomes alive.

> Allah once asked all the created souls, "who is your Lord?". All the souls said "You are our Creator our Lord". But souls forget the covenant when they descend to the earth. Some have faint or vague memory of Allah (God) in the inner core of the heart.

Allah created all the souls, so how are they brothers and sisters? Their bodies are made from the bodies of a man and woman but their soul is an individual spirit which has been predestined to be breathed into a body which had been created by a man and woman. It doesn't make us spiritually related. They are biologically our parents but spiritually, they are not our brothers and sisters.

The definition of a brother or sister is:

> A man/woman or boy/girl in relation to other sons and daughters of his parents.

The only way you can be a son/daughter is biologically therefore you can only be a brother or sister of somone biologically.

And Allah knows best.